# Hide Datagrid Column based on its Property name

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` defined as follows :

```
<DataGrid Name="dtMydatagrid" Margin="10,10,10,10" RowHeight="20" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="auto" Width="auto">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox x:Name="TXT" Background="Transparent" Width="15" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsBKM}" Value="true">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="AQUA" TargetName="TXT"/>
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="TXT"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now,  I have a boolean property in my class named `IsBKM` to which the `DataGridTemplateColumn` is bounded. 
So, it is displayed by as `CheckBox`.
I don't want to display the `IsBKM` column in my `DataGrid`. Can I use a trigger and hide the column whose name is `IsBKM` or ***any different solution***?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the [`DataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratedcolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the column's `Visibility` property from there. You should be able to do something like this:

```
private void DataGridAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
    DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid != null && IsBKM) dataGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You can use the `e.Column.Header` property to check the name of the column and then use that instead. However, your column has no `Header` currently set. You *could* also set the column name (in XAML) and then check for that `Name` value instead of using the `Header` property:

```
private void DataGridAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
    DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Name == "IsBKM" && IsBKM)
    {
        e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant I check the column name in my xaml instead.

Comment: You can loop through the `Columns` collection until you find one with `Header == "the column header text"` and then use that instead. However, your column has no `Header` currently set. You *could* also set the column name (in XAML) and then check for that `Name` value instead of using the `Header` property.

Comment: no need to iterate through all the columns, you have all you need in the event arguments: if (e.PropertyName == "IsBKM") e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed.

Comment: @Dtex, you're assuming that the user wants to do this for every column.

Comment: no, just for the column that will bind ot the IdBKM property. Your solution will be called for every column too (iterating through the columns collection each time).

Comment: Hold up... there is no column `Binding` to the `IsBKM` property, so you can't use `e.PropertyName`... That won't work. I think you meant this maybe?: `if (e.Column.Name == "IsBKM") e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`