# MvvmLight - Hiding IsInDesignMode in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

MvvmLight's `ViewModelBase` type has a property `IsInDesignMode` inherited by all subclasses.

My `MainWindow` ViewModel resembles this:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> People { get; }
}

class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase {
}
```

My XAML for the DataGrid is exactly only this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}" />`
```

When I run the application, I see all of my `PersonViewModel`'s properties, but  `IsInDesignMode` as one of the columns. This is undesirable.

I also have another `ViewModel` that represents another entity, `ProductViewModel` that has extensible properties by way of a property `ObservableCollection<Pair<String,String>>` where each `Pair<String,String>` entry represents an additional column name and its value respectively.

#### Non-working solution:

To solve the `IsInDesignMode` problem, I implemented `PersonViewModel : ICustomTypeDescriptor` and in the `GetProperties` method I remove the `IsInDesignMode` property, however when the DataGrid renders my collection it still has that column. I set a breakpoint in `GetProperties` and it is being called, so I don't know why WPF isn't respecting the results.

```
class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICustomTypeDescriptor {
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( this, attributes, true ).Where( pd => pd.Name != "IsInDesignMode" )
        );
    }
}
```

I also changed `ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> People` to `TypedListObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>` which is a class with this definition:

```
public class TypedListObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ITypedList
{
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
       return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( typeof(T));
    }
```

...however this doesn't cause WPF to respect my logic and hide the `IsInDesignMode` column.

Comment: Could you provide the code of `ViewModelBase` ?

Comment: @Guerudo `ViewModelBase` is online here: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V3/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight (NET35)/ViewModelBase.cs

Comment: Could you post your full xaml code ?

Comment: @Guerudo The rest of my XAML is irrelevant to this question, I'm only interested in the `<DataGrid />`. Is there anything in particular you'd like to know?

Comment: Yeah I meant the full code of your `DataGrid`. Is that all you have in your `DataGrid` ?

Comment: @Guerudo Correct, I'm a XAML-minimalist :)

Comment: Since you said that you are using MvvmLight, you should normally be able to modify `ViewModelBase`. If it is the case then just try to add the attribute `[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]` on the property `IsInDesignMode`

Comment: I want to say you have to use an attribute to specify what custom type descriptor to use for a given type, and not just implement ICustomTypeDescriptor.  A minute's research didn't reveal, and it's been a while since I've done this (I can guarantee it works).  Alternatively, you can hide the column via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231803/hide-datagrid-column-based-on-its-property-name or you can define the columns yourself rather than let them be automatically generated.  Your choice, but either should work.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the ViewModelBase inheritance to ObservableObject. 
This is a lighter base class but includes all the INotifyPropertyChange encapsulation, but without the IsInDesign property.